# How can I keep floating image matched when printed?

Tags: microsoft-word

How to keep floating image/diagram from jumping around in the print process. This images/diagrams are created in word using the shapes and text boxes. Ones the diagram is created and it within the margins and looks good when you printed it, it show up out of sync from the original picture. I solved it by saving the word document as a pdf and then print it. However, and curious to find out if there is a setting in word to keep it fix for the printing process?

Comment: Unless things have REALLY changed, Word is a "word processor" and does not provide element assembling and processing capability. You can't natively "fix" elements in place. You are looking for what used to be called a Desktop Publishing program.

Comment: Requesting directions to programs is specifically prohibited in the FAQ.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Where does it say that? I don't think they are asking how to use Word. They are asking how to overcome the problem with things moving when they print. That is on topic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was refering to my statement about a DTP. I have not voted to close. I look forward to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me before. To resolve it, I used the `Group` feature on the 'Drawing Tools > Format' tab.

[image]

Select the items you want to group by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on each item. Then click the grouping icon and select `Group`. This lock the items together and they will stay together when you print.

More details about using the grouping feature - [Group or ungroup shapes, pictures, or other objects](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-shapes-pictures-or-other-objects-a7374c35-20fe-4e0a-9637-7de7d844724b).